# Remove SOAP Envelepoe and soap Body element from XMLDOCUMENt

Tags: c#, web-services, xmldocument

is there a easy way to remove the

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema">
       <soap:Body>
           <input1>jsdhkfh</input1>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>

TO

<input1>jsdhkfh</input1>
```

i have XMLDocument object that i need to transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typing directly thus there could be some syntactic errors but atleast give you the idea.

```
XMLDocument document = ...
 XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
document.loadxml(document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("soap:Body",nsmgr).ChildNodes[0].OuterXml);
```